# How to get ownership of your work when you are all over the place?

Tags: career-development, telecommute

I work remotely for a US company. I do customer support, training, onboarding; presales, lead generation, identification of potential collaborators; project management and keeping track of everything that is going on in the region, including dozens of projects and more than 50 customers.
I also represent the company in the region, as there's nobody else to physically attend events, unless they fly somebody over.

Despite me running all over the place, I don't have a senior role in the company. The company is growing, and now we hired even more experienced people for functions like marketing and sales.

In the US, the new execs have already hired people they previously worked with, pushing down some of my older colleagues (but presenting their slides at strategy meetings!).

I am afraid that the same execs will eventually split my tasks among people they will hire, leaving me with nothing to do but (maybe) customer support.

To get established and diminish the chance of being "eaten away", I think I would need to take ownership of my work and list projects and achievements.

**Note that when my work leads to something serious, execs get involved or fly over, and I don't get involved or updated any further.**

My question is: running all over the place as a "non-senior" remote employee, how can I take ownership of my work and get established?

Comment: to get recognition and credit for what I do, and to be actively involved in the business opportunity I generate.

Comment: How large is your company (# of employees)? What's been your role in prior companies? Has your current role here always been like this, or slowly drifted to where it is now?

Comment: 80, head of a department (in startups), I have been doing this since I joined the company

Comment: Is there some kind of written document that records what you do in your job ? e.g: a report you give to your boss every day/week/month.

Comment: I do report in detail everything I do. the problem is that sometimes I put "nothing happened this week" while some manager concluded a deal with somebody I started working with, and nobody tells me anything. This way, then something is realised I can't take credit because I was not involved at the end, even if it was me who started the interaction. And I don't do sales, so I can't take credit for how happy our customers are before they pay up.

Comment: Can't you detail on how you started the interaction ? And how is the company getting information on how happy your customers are?

Comment: Have you thought about approaching your higher up management to promote you and make you a lead? You can explain to them your roles and your contribution to the success of the company and you would like to be more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a few things to you.

1. Be your own cheerleading team. It is important that the success
   your generate for the company is recognised by the company as having
   come from you - but that doesn't necessarily come across in reports
   no matter how detailed.  It is an absolute truism that in our
   professional lives it is extremely rare for someone else to blow our
   trumpet - we need to focus on that ourselves. So to do this - you
   need to actively seek out opportunities to personally point out your
   successes. You don't need to point out every one - and you need to
   be careful not to do it too much, but a bit of self promotion will
   go a long way to being recognised in the fashion you are looking
   for.
2. Evaluate carefully the culture of your company. Is it changing? Is
   it still the company you were excited about when you joined? Is it
   a company that you want to be recognised at? This evaluation needs
   to be honest. It could ultimately determine for you that you don't
   care about recognition, because the company is no longer a good fit
   for you. No longer being a good fit for you, would lead naturally
   into looking for a company, and a role, that is a good fit for you
   and what you want to achieve. If there are new execs coming in, and
   they are making the kind of changes you describe - that is a
   definite personal risk that you need to evaluate for yourself, and
   you should carefully consider your situation in light of that risk -
   which leads on to my next point:
3. Evaluate yourself. Have you changed away from what you were when
   you first began this role? Are you now looking for different aims
   and goals? Is it time for you to seek something different? This
   would lead to you identifying what you personally want and your
   current 5 year plan. If you don't have a 5 year plan - develop one.
   Once you have evaluated yourself, you may just find this company and
   role is what you actually want - in which case it is crucial to
   resolve the challenge you point out. If not - there are other
   challenges to resolve, and you can stop spending energy on this
   issue, and start spending all your spare energy on your personal
   plans.
4. Ask for help. An additional strategy is to seek out 1 or more
   leaders in the organisation and ask for mentoring.  This strategy is
   equally valid if your personal reflection is likely to lead you into
   a different company and culture, because reaching out to Execs for
   mentoring is developing a network that can assist you within the
   company AND OUTSIDE IT TOO! The execs you reach out to for
   mentoring should be ones that you feel you already have a degree of
   rapport with, and should definitely have a cultural approach and
   philosophy that is compatible with your own. Find the right
   opportunities to meet with your mentors in person, and be direct in
   asking for professional development. This approach also gives you
   the opportunity to ask them - "Is there anyone else within your
   network that you would be comfortable introducing me to so I can
   also ask them for Mentoring?" (*Obviously in your own words*) If you
   do get such an introduction, it begins the building of a network
   outside your existing company, and that is something really
   important to nurture and build before it becomes urgent.  When it is
   urgent, you are are not in the best frame of mind to get it right,
   and so doing it now both comes across as more genuine and is more
   likely to build an effective network that can support and grow you
   long term.

I wish you the best of luck in this journey, it is not an easy one and we all struggle at times with shifting sands underfoot an this appears to be part of what you are currently wrestling with.  Remember to take care of your health, both mental and physical!